# PL SQL trigger When Insert a table insert into another Table

Tags: oracle

I attached two table below I need a trigger when insert do_chd table in same time insert in do_chd_hist table And DO_MST table to DO_MST_HIST TAbLE

```
create table do_mst
 ( fdo_no varchar2(14) not null,
 fdo_date date not null,
 code_db varchar2(11),
 db_name varchar2(25),
 code_sdb varchar2(11),
 sdb_name varchar2(25),
 code_sst varchar2(11),
 sst_name varchar2(25),
 constraint fdo_no_pk primary key(fdo_no)
 );

create table do_mst_hist
 ( fdo_no varchar2(14) not null,
 fdo_date date not null,
 code_db varchar2(11),
 db_name varchar2(25),
 code_sdb varchar2(11),
 sdb_name varchar2(25),
 code_sst varchar2(11),
 sst_name varchar2(25),
 constraint fdo_no_pk primary key(fdo_no)
 );

create table do_chd
 ( fdo_no varchar2(14) not null,
 itemcode varchar2(11) not null,
 name varchar(27) not null,
 unit_price varchar2(11),
 req_qty number(11) not null,
 total_price number(14),
 unit varchar2(7),
 constraint fdo_no_fk foreign key(fdo_no)
 references do_mst(fdo_no)
 );

create table do_chd_hist
 ( fdo_no varchar2(14) not null,
 itemcode varchar2(11) not null,
 name varchar(27) not null,
 unit_price varchar2(11),
 req_qty number(11) not null,
 total_price number(14),
 unit varchar2(7),
 constraint fdo_no_fk foreign key(fdo_no)
 references do_mst(fdo_no)
 );
```

Can anybody help me to write this trigger?

Comment: I am sure the docs will help you if you search for them on google. You need to show some effort.

Comment: Liton, this site is not a code writing service where you can get your work done by others for free.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I find it offending that a user believes that we are here to do his/her work. The op clearly does not show any effort and declares the intention to use freely the work of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with what being said in the comments, I don't think there's a reason to think twice about writing up a create trigger syntax, and I'm happy to show you the solution to your problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER do_chd_insert_trg
  AFTER INSERT do_chd
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    sal_diff number;
BEGIN
    insert into do_chd_hist
    values (new.fdo_no, new.itemcode, new.name, new.unit_price, new.req_try, new.total_price, new.unit);
END;
/
```

You can use this syntax to generate the trigger to the second table, after changing the respectable column names.
You can read more about oracle trigger syntax here -
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm

Comment: Yaron Idan I wanna thanks for your Answer but it's not working yet. there are a compilation Error.